# List working with multiple blocks

Tags: c#, .net

List is a wrapper over array. While you add items to the list it creates bigger and bigger array undercover (and previous array is garbage collected). But if you treat large lists at some point you will get OutOfMemoryException even if there is free memory due to memory fragmentation. I am looking for an ICollection implementation which would work with set of arrays undercover similar to what [MemoryTributary](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/348590/A-replacement-for-MemoryStream) does.

**Update.**

I have found BigArray implementation here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joshwil/archive/2005/08/10/450202.aspx.

While it tries to solve other problem (creating an array of >2GB size), it solves my problem too. But this implementation is not full and even does not compile. So if I don't find any better, I will improve this one and use it.

Comment: How big is your collection actually going to get? For reference types, the data used by the objects themselves would usually end up being much larger than the array, so this is rarely an issue.

Comment: @JonSkeet, 400mb of doubles

Comment: 400MB, or 400 million? (Factor of 8 difference!) Also, what CPU architecture are you running on, and what version of .NET? .NET 4.5 on x64 allows larger arrays if you turn on the right flag.

Comment: What *is* an issue in low-memory situations is the fact that arrays larger than around 85K go onto the large-object heap, and therefore will not be moved around in memory to make room for new allocations. This can cause major memory fragmentation, and is an issue that we had problems with. And arrays of doubles are even worse - they go onto the large object heap if there's more than 1000 of them! So it's not the overall memory use that's a problem; instead, it's the fragmentation caused by objects being placed on the large object heap.

Comment: @JonSkeet, 400MB. I am running x64 .NET 4 but I need to support x86 users too (desktop application).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found any good implementation. So I have written my own ChunkyList. Generally ChunkyList is a List of arrays wrapper. Initially block has size of 1 but it is multiplied by two (when it reaches MaxBlockSize, a next block is created) every time you need to extend the current block (the behavior similar to the List).

Here is a generic ChunkyList:

```
public class ChunkyList<T> : IList<T>
{
    public ChunkyList()
    {
        MaxBlockSize = 65536;
    }

    public ChunkyList(int maxBlockSize)
    {
        MaxBlockSize = maxBlockSize;
    }

    private List<T[]> _blocks = new List<T[]>();

    public int Count { get; private set; }

    public int MaxBlockSize { get; private set; }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        var index = 0;
        foreach (var items in _blocks)
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                yield return item;
                if (Count <= ++index)
                    break;
            }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        var indexInsideBlock = GetIndexInsideBlock(Count);
        if (indexInsideBlock == 0)
            _blocks.Add(new T[1]);
        else
        {
            var lastBlockIndex = _blocks.Count - 1;
            var lastBlock = _blocks[lastBlockIndex];
            if(indexInsideBlock >= lastBlock.Length)
            {
                var newBlockSize = lastBlock.Length*2;
                if (newBlockSize >= MaxBlockSize)
                    newBlockSize = MaxBlockSize;

                _blocks[lastBlockIndex] = new T[newBlockSize];
                Array.Copy(lastBlock, _blocks[lastBlockIndex], lastBlock.Length);
            }
        }

        _blocks[GetBlockIndex(Count)][indexInsideBlock] = item;

        Count++;
    }

    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
            Add(item);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool Contains(T item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool Remove(T item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public int IndexOf(T item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Insert(int index, T item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            if (index >= Count)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("index");

            var blockIndex = GetBlockIndex(index);
            var block = _blocks[blockIndex];

            return block[GetIndexInsideBlock(index)];
        }
        set { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    private int GetBlockIndex(int index)
    {
        return index / MaxBlockSize;
    }

    private long GetIndexInsideBlock(int index)
    {
        return index % MaxBlockSize;
    }
}
```

And here are tests which prove this implementation works:

```
 [TestClass]
    public class ChunkyListTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
         public void GetEnumerator_NoItems()
         {
             var chunkyList = new ChunkyList<float>();

             var wasInsideForeach = false;
             foreach (var item in chunkyList)
                 wasInsideForeach = true;

             Assert.IsFalse(wasInsideForeach);
         }

        [TestMethod]
        public void GetEnumerator_MaxBlockSizeOfThreeWithThreeItems()
        {
            var chunkyList = new ChunkyList<float> (3) { 1, 2, 3 };

            var wasInsideForeach = false;
            var iteratedItems = new List<float>();
            foreach (var item in chunkyList)
            {
                wasInsideForeach = true;
                iteratedItems.Add(item);
            }

            Assert.IsTrue(wasInsideForeach);
            CollectionAssert.AreEqual(new List<float> { 1, 2, 3 }, iteratedItems);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void GetEnumerator_MaxBlockSizeOfTwoWithThreeItems()
        {
            var chunkyList = new ChunkyList<float>(2) {1,2,3};
            var wasInsideForeach = false;
            var iteratedItems = new List<float>();

            foreach (var item in chunkyList)
            {
                wasInsideForeach = true;
                iteratedItems.Add(item);
            }

            Assert.IsTrue(wasInsideForeach);
            CollectionAssert.AreEqual(new List<float>() { 1, 2, 3 }, iteratedItems);
            Assert.AreEqual(chunkyList.MaxBlockSize, 2);
        }
    }
```

P. S. I have implemented only those IList methods which are used in my code. So you are welcome to improve this implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize a List with a capacity if you have a rough estimate of the maximum size. As far as I know, that will avoid the heavy garbage collection happening (with the old smaller arrays), which might also avoid the memory fragmentation.

Comment: It doesn't help to solve described problem. As soon I specify capacity of millions and millions of doubles, it will try to create an array of appropriate size. But it will fail with OutOfMemoryException due to situation described by Matthew Watson in question comments section. If you are curions about working solution, please look at my answer.